# For loop inside matplotlib.animation (FuncAnimation) to evaluate variable at every step for all points

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to find the best way to use `KDTree.query_ball_point` function to find the concentration of particles within 'r' distance, for every particle at each step of the animation, and have the number value from this count used in the `conc` equation. Essentially I am trying to make the settling (stokes) velocity a function of the concentration of surrounding particles.

So far my attempts have not worked, below is the code I am working with (excluding my failed KDTree attempts)

I have changed the "r" (radius) so there is no variation in the size of particles so that the effects of the concentration on particle settling velocity can be observed more clearly (currently not working at all). However, "c" within the for loop must be doing something because the animation is working (will not work without "c").

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import pdb
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

n=5
sigma=0.01


#m = np.random.uniform(n)

pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) (Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)

pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)

g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)

r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)

mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)

rp = 0.0005 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
az = plt.axes(xlim=(-1, 1), ylim=(-100, 0))
xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro', animated=True)

#pdb.set_trace()
def v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu):
    top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
    bottom=9*mu
    ws=top/bottom
    return ws

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln,

def concentration(xdata, ydata, rp):
    pdb.set_trace()
    coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
    tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
    test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
    nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp) #nearest neighbors as a list 
                    #(had tree in here before test but shape was wrong)
    nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt)): 
        nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
    return nnt,

def update(frame):
    global xdata
    global ydata
    global rp
    global concentration
    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)
    #ydata = ydata + np.random.normal(-0.1, sigma, n)
    wss = v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu)
    if frame == 0.0:
        ydata = np.zeros(len(xdata)) #makes the ydata length = xdata at 
                                     #time 0
    cp = concentration(xdata, ydata, rp)
    ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                init_func=init, blit=True, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `for c in conc:` - nothing in the for loop suite makes use of `c`, in fact `c` is assigned a new value on each iteration, `c = len(index)`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @wwii I guess this is where I am confused. Should I bring my 'conc' equation into the for loop and have 'c' evaluated within the loop at every step? if so, does 'wn' pull 'c' from the for loop at every step for each particle? see edits in code above

Comment: `return c,` - this line seems erroneous, are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: `conc = (1-c)` - `c` has not yet been defined when this statement executes; it should throw a NameError exception.  Please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: @wwii no but I just figured out why it was working for me (and possibly not you) I had 'c' in 'global', I do get an error when it is removed

Comment: I will read through the links, Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement